# Live Event Schedule

Tags: web-apps, project-management, web-services

I would like to show a live schedule for an event on some extra screens.

For this i need a webservice where i can enter a schedule in some kind of backend, which then gives me a link I can enter on the PCs connected to the screens. It should show the schedule and update automatically when the schedule is changed.

I have made a simple wireframe of what the service should display. I am flexible regarding the layout, output and design. A free service would be best, but also commercial ones are relevant. However, the tool should be simple, as I don't need many extra features.

Here is an example of what I have in mind:
[image]